# sbt настройка удалённого репозитория

Tags: сборка, хранилище, sbt

Имеем компьютер в локальной сети на котором необходимо настроить репозиторий библиотек для загрузки их с помощью [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/). Чтобы я один раз собрал библиотеки, опубликовал их на этом сервере, а все остальные в локальной сети могли просто добавить в `Build.scala` ссылку на этот локальный сервер и оно оттуда забирало необходимые библиотеки.

Что из себя представляет такой репозиторий (я так понимаю, это maven репозиторий), это обычный FTP сервер? Если нет, то какими инструментами реализуется данная задача?

Comment: какая ОС используется? можно немного больше деталей?

Comment: Linux, Debian, какие ещё подробности интересуют?

Comment: меня заинтересовал этот вопрос т.к. сетевые репозитарии  дистрибутива я делал но не для разработчиков. пытаюсь разобраться в чем разница.

Comment: допустим, мы хотим какую-нибудь библиотеку подключить к проекту, мы указываем в depencies ссылку на эту либу - sbt лезет в какой-нибудь из указанных maven репозиториев и загружает её оттуда. Мне нужно сделать аналог вот такого же maven репозитория, где надо будет хранить собранные библиотеки

Comment: @Umed вот эта статья, думаю, должна Вам помочь: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository

Comment: @EugeneG.Ustimenko, спасибо, попробую разобраться:)

Comment: @Umed эти разбирал я но без пока четкого ответа у меня нет.

 http://xgu.ru/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_Ubuntu.


http://www.devbug.info/2015/08/ubuntu-installing-scala-sbt-ide.html

буду разбираться для себя.

Comment: @айтишник, это не то, мне надо с сервера локального общие библиотеки раздавать, чтобы каждый их у себя не собирал

Comment: @Umed понимаю. я вот что нашел https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/maven-repository-builder (он же libmaven-repository-builder-java если я правильно понял). общая картина прояснилась но есть еще пробелы...